# Excel VBA prevent SaveAs .xlsx

Tags: excel, vba

I produce a suite of Scorecard calculators with macros. I distribute the workbooks as .xls files. However, sometimes a user will save the workbook as an .xlsx file and thereby removing all the VBA code and macros. The built-in functions obviously no longer work.

Is there any way I can make the standard Excel SaveAs function exclude .xlsx as an option?

Comment: Sorry to all... The title should have been VBA not VBD....

Comment: That'll be difficult to achieve. I had the same problem with my co-workers. You can basically create a specific button to do the macro saves as for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

You may replace the standard FileSave dialog by your own. Unfortunately you cannot manipulate the Filter list to remove anything but ".xlsm" and ".xls" but you can catch the selected file name and act accordingly ...

suggestion:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim FD As FileDialog, FTyp As Long

    MsgBox "Sub Workbook_BeforeSave"

    ' this Sub will never save, we save through the Dialog box below
    Cancel = True

    ' reference a SaveAs Dialog
    Set FD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
    FD.Show

    If FD.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Nothing chosen"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        ' check for proper extension
        If Right(FD.SelectedItems(1), 3) = "xls" Or Right(FD.SelectedItems(1), 4) = "xlsm" Then
            MsgBox "saving as " & FD.SelectedItems(1)

            If Right(FD.SelectedItems(1), 3) = "xls" Then
                ' different enum before Excel 2007
                If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
                    FTyp = -4143           ' xls pre-2007
                Else
                    FTyp = 56              ' xls post-2007
                End If
            Else
                FTyp = 52                  ' xlsm post-2007
            End If

            ' we don't want to come here again, so temporarily switch off event handling
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Me.SaveAs FD.SelectedItems(1), FTyp
            Application.EnableEvents = True

        Else
            MsgBox "selected wrong file format ... not saving"
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks MikeD. We eventually worked this out with something very similar to what you have shown. Greatly appreciated the help.